# Custom Axis Scale in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js, scale, axes

Is there a way to use a function (probably needing a forward and reverse transform) to create a custom axis scale in Chart.js?
I'm looking for something similar to what is possible in [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/scales/custom_scale.html).
I know it is possible to do a logarithmic scaled axis is Chart.js, but what about a Weibull Scaled Axis or a Normal Scaled Axis?
[image: Weibull Probability Plot]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/axes.html. This is the official docs for creating a new axis/scale